# Hide a message box via assembly

Tags: assembly, mfc, ida

One really old program of mine has a message box of an error which keeps being displayed and I need to get rid of it. I've lost the source so I'm using assembly now:

The section with the assembly and message box looks like

```
Cmp, ebx 4F6h
Jl short loc 10000dec
Push 30h
Push offset caption ; error ...
Push offset detailsitspast08
Push 0
Call ds: messageboxa
```

How can I modify this so it doesn't display the message box?

Comment: Replace all five instructions after `JL` with a sequence of NOPs (0x90).

Comment: Are the length of those pushes equal to those nops?

Comment: No, a NOP takes up a single byte. All the bytes belonging to those five instructions need to be rewritten. How to do that depends on what tools are used (OllyDbg, IDA, etc).

Comment: I'm using IDA, but I can use another tool if need be

Comment: The program just crashed, maybe pressing ok does something extra to memory?

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the surrounding code, or even better the actual executable file.

Comment: If you are NOP'ing 19 bytes of instructions (which you are) then you need to use 19 NOPs.  Even though you are replacing 5 instructions, you cannot change the size of anything in the code section that easily.  So, 5 instructions = 19 bytes then you need 19 NOP's.  Without seeing the surrounding code, it might be easier to just change the jmp to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDA is fine, but you'll need a hex-editor as well, such as [Hex Workshop](http://www.hexworkshop.com/) or [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm). Here's how you can do it:

In IDA, focus the text cursor in the first line you want to replace, `push 30h`. Look at the left part of the statusbar below the disassembly window. You should see two hex addresses - the physical and the virtual. Take note of the physical one. Now focus on the first instruction *after* `call ds:MessageBoxA`. Again take note of the physical address.

Open the executable in the hex editor (make a backup first!), and navigate to the first physical address. Make sure you're overwriting the bytes rather than inserting them, and keep writing the `0x90` value until you reach the second address. Don't overwrite it.

Save this changed file under a different name, open it in another instance of IDA (if you overwrite the original file, IDA will not be able to open the new one side by side), navigate to the virtual address, and check that all the bytes have been replaced correctly. That's it.

Hint: if you go to IDA's *Options* > *General* and set *Number of opcode bytes* to a non-zero value, such as 10, you will see the bytes making up each instruction on the left. You can count these to make sure you replaced the right number of bytes. (Or you can just subtract start address from end address, obviously).

Here's an example screenshot (the application in the shot is of course different, but the gist is the same):

Before:

[image: The original instructions]

After:

[image: The changed instructions]